# How to refine the mandatory property of nodes from a grouping in YANG language?

Tags: model-driven, ietf-netmod-yang

I defined a grouping which has a leaf with mandatory property set to false.
But in some cases, I would like to use this grouping and specify that the leaf should be mandatory. How do I achieve this in YANG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the `refine` statement when specifying a use of your grouping.

```
module mandatory-and-grouping {
  namespace "org:example:mandatory-and-grouping";
  prefix "mag";

  grouping my-grouping {
    leaf my-leaf {
      type string;
    }
  }

  container top {
    uses my-grouping {
      refine my-leaf {
        mandatory true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> 7.13.2.  The "refine" Statement

> Some of the properties of each node in the grouping can be refined
> with the "refine" statement.  The argument is a string that
> identifies a node in the grouping.  This node is called the refine's
> target node.  If a node in the grouping is not present as a target
> node of a "refine" statement, it is not refined and thus is used
> exactly as it was defined in the grouping.

> The argument string is a descendant schema node identifier (see
> [Section 6.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-6.5)).

> The following refinements can be done:

> - A leaf or choice node may get a default value, or a new default
>   value if it already had one.

> - A leaf-list node may get a set of default values, or a new set of
>   default values if it already had defaults; i.e., the set of
>   refined default values replaces the defaults already given.

> - Any node may get a specialized "description" string.

> - Any node may get a specialized "reference" string.

> - Any node may get a different "config" statement.

> - **A leaf, anydata, anyxml, or choice node may get a different
>   "mandatory" statement.**

> - A container node may get a "presence" statement.

> - A leaf, leaf-list, list, container, anydata, or anyxml node may
>   get additional "must" expressions.

> - A leaf-list or list node may get a different "min-elements" or
>   "max-elements" statement.

> - A leaf, leaf-list, list, container, choice, case, anydata, or
>   anyxml node may get additional "if-feature" expressions.

> - Any node can get refined extensions, if the extension allows
>   refinement.  See [Section 7.19](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.19) for details.

> [RFC7950, Section 7.13.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.13.2)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve similar thing when we need to reuse the same grouping at different place by changing the range value?

Comment: @DarshanL, changing a `range` would be an attempt to change an already defined type of a node in the grouping. This cannot be done, unless you resort to deviations (target would be a schema node, not grouping content). If you need to further restrict a range of values of a node in the grouping, and alternative would be to refine the target with a `must` instead - express the constraint as an XPath expression. You cannot extend the defined range that way, however.